# centos cannot coredump with ulimit -c is unlimited

Tags: centos, coredump, ulimit

I just installed CentOs 7 on my mac using Parallel Desktop.

Here is the result of `ulimit -c`:

> [root@centos-linux test1]# ulimit -c
>   unlimited

Here is the content of /etc/security/limits.conf

- soft core unlimited

But the is no coredump file created.

What else can I do to enable coredump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phenomenon results from false core dump file path.

I thought the coredump file should be created in current dir or /tmp. But it's not.

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` tells where the coredump files are.

In my system:

> [root@centos-linux Linux]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
>   /mydata/corefile/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t

However, there is no `/mydata/corefile` in my system.

So I can created a new dir `/mydata/corefile` or using

`sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t`

to get coredump file in /tmp.